# UIActivityViewControlller hyperlink

Tags: html, ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

How can I share a hyperlink using UIActivityViewController. Currently I am using html tags inside the NSString. For the email, the hyperlink works fine but for Twitter, Facebook, Message activities, i get the raw text.

How can I add a hyperlink to work for all the activities?

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourUrl];

    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                                                     applicationActivities:nil];
```